# Excel 2010 - Multiple Types of Locks on the Same Sheet

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to create an excel sheet that handles a user input/output task (I know that this is a kludge at best and offensive at worst).  So I want the user to be able to edit the input cells (and only the input cells), and select (but not edit) the outputs.

Example: Grid A1:C3.  A1:A3 are completely locked - unselectable.  B1:B3 are selectable and editable.  C1:C3 are selectable and uneditable.

Is this possible?  My gut is telling me no, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using worksheet protection:

In the Format Cells dialog of the cells B1:B3, uncheck the "Protected" checkbox in the last tab (Protection). Then protect the worksheet (right click the worksheet tab at the bottom->Protect Sheet). Once the sheet is protected, the user can only edit those cells that are unprotected.

Regarding the selection of C1:C3 and non-selection of A1:A3 - you can allow/prevent the user from selecting protect cells in the same sheet protection dialog. However, this is a sheet wide setting, so be default you can only fully prevent selecting all protect cells or allow selection of all cells.

If you only want prevent selection of A1:A3 because you don't want the user to see the formula, just check "Hidden" in the Format cells dialog - this way the user does not see the formula.

If you really need to separate between selectable and unselectable, either split across two worksheets - or use a little VBA macro. To do so, open the VBA editor (Alt+F11) and double click your worksheet in the top-left list. In the code window, enter the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Me.ProtectContents And Intersect(Target, Range("B1:C3")) Is Nothing Then Range("B1").Select
End Sub
```

This way, every time a cell outside your required range is selected, B1 is selected instead